# How to handle multiple collision type in c++?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm building a game in c++ using Qt. I got the collision detection right using GraphicsItem methods the thing is that I don't know how to deal with every different collision type as there is different objects with different behaviour.

Comment: Just use different algorithms.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875830/how-to-implement-collision-effects-in-a-game/1876578#1876578

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually possible to know which kind of object participate in the collision, through custom type, see the documentation for more info http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#type

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using one of the `collidingItems` or `collidesWithItem` methods. From these you get a list of `QGraphicsItem`s. Then it is just a matter of casting to determine what hit what and reacting.