# How to check if an object is derived from specific class at runtime?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, typeid

I want to handle all of the children of specific class the same way.

So far I have been checking with `dynamic_cast` like this:

```
if(dynamic_cast<ParentClass*>(child_object))
{
  // handle the object
}
```

In the case I do not really need to cast the child object to use it, is there a better way of doing this?

My first attempt was:

```
if(std::is_base_of<ParentClass, typeid(child_object)>::value)
```

which of course does not work as the `is_base_of` expects two `class` arguments and the `typeid()` returns the `std::type_info`.

So my question is, what is the proper way of doing this? Or is the `dynamic_cast` the right facility to use even if the casted object is not used?

### Update

Here is the concrete example of what I am trying to achieve. I am iterating over all the `QGraphicsItem` objects that are in collision with my object of interest. I want to handle only one group of those objects and ignore the rest. That group of objects has a common parent. So again is using the `dynamic_cast` the way to go, or are there better alternatives?

```
    for(QGraphicsItem* i : collidingItems())
    {
        if(dynamic_cast<ParentClass*>(i))
        {
            // handle specific group of objects that 
            //are children of ParentClass
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ordinarily you don't need to do *anything* to access base class functionality. What's the concrete problem at hand? Do add a **complete but minimal** example that readers can compile and try out.

Comment: Why not have an abstract virtual function in the base class, that is implemented/overridden in the child classes, and you just call that?

Comment: You're looking for `decltype`, not `typeid`. But indeed, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @Quentin `decltype` is evaluated during compilation not execution.

Comment: @Glapa It's a template argument, so there's no going around providing it at compile-time. Classes can't change bases at runtime anyway, so it's all pointless.

Comment: @Quentin Ah sorry I didn't noticed it at first, my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` is the way to go. It is the only way to detect if the object is part of the inheritance tree for a certain class, since `typeid` will only give you the actual name of the class.

That being said, if something specific needs to be done on objects of a given class, it should be a virtual method. Using RTTI is bad form usually, but especially here.

Comment: This answer fits a question about downcasting, but this one is about upcasting.

Comment: @slaphappy Could you please elaborate on your last sentence. I have read about how expensive RTTI is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579887/how-expensive-is-rtti) (I like the answer from user Marius). But what do you mean by it is especially bad form here? From what I see, I do not have an alternative to the `dynamic_cast` in my case.