# Disable dynamic binding (virtual table creation) in c++ for virtual functions

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, vtable

I recently I came across a C++ interview question which got me very intrigued:

Suppose you declare mistakenly some C++ member function as virtual, but (maybe for performance reasons) you want to prevent the compiler from creating a v-table for this function. That is, disable thee dynamic function binding in favor of a static binding.

How would you achieve this? Also, are there some C++11 specific ways of doing so?

Comment: Rewrite everything in the codebase which is depend on dynamic binding... :D (seriously, in interviews i always give stupid answers for stupid questions, it works)

Comment: If you use virtual functions, you have a virtual table. If you don't want a virtual table, don't use virtual functions

Comment: @Gombat If you have a vtable is merely compiler implementation specific, c++ standard doesn't state such concept.

Comment: You can perform a non-virtual call to a virtual function like `obj->BaseClass::my_function()`. But it affects only a single function call, and the vftable is created anyway.

Comment: If you are interested in stupid solutions: `#define virtual `, but it is hard to isolate such a bad thing=)
Btw you can do some steps to make manual removal of `virtual` keywords simpler and more reliable.

Comment: @stgatilov: But if you just remove virtual keyword your program will work wrongly. :D

Comment: Maybe the question really was that bad, or maybe you changed the meaning in paraphrasing the question.  Either way, maybe they were just asking how to bypass the virtual binding and directly call a specific class's binding, as in `name::function(...)`

Comment: @Melkon: Well, do some humble debugging effort and set proper static class at each call =) If polymorphism is used (and most certainly it is), then you are screwed. Perhaps you can reinvent the wheel and implement your own vftables then =)

Comment: `#define virtual` and don't use any 3rd party library.

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware of no way to coerce a C++ compiler to disable dynamic binding, short of forcing it to compile code purely as C if it supports such an option (which not all C++ compilers do, but most do).   However, that is sort of throwing out the baby with the bathwater, as it notionally disables all C++ features that are not part of C.

There is, of course, the `final` identifier introduced in C++11, which prevents further derivation from a class or overriding of virtual members.   Strictly speaking, this does not prevent dynamic dispatch though - it addresses a different problem.

One way to avoid implications (perceived or actual) of dynamic binding is to avoid using or writing any classes with virtual member functions, and to not create a class hierarchy (i.e. don't derive from classes with virtual functions).   Clearly, if there are no virtual functions in play, there is no need for virtual function dispatch, and therefore no need for dynamic binding.

If you know the type of an object, it is possible to avoid use of dynamic binding by using static dispatch i.e. explicitly naming which function to call.   For example, let's say we have a class `Base` that provides a `public` `virtual` member named `foo()` and a class named `Derived` that inherits from `Base` and overrides `foo()`.   Then the following avoids doing dynamic dispatch;

```
 Base *b = new Derived;
 b->Base::foo();          //   static call;  will not call `Derived::foo()`
 b->Derived::Foo();       // incorrect static call.  Will not compile since b is a pointer to Base not Derived

 Derived *d = new Derived;
 d->Derived::foo();       // static call of Derived::foo()
 d->Base::foo();          // static call of Base::foo()
```

Of course, if the code which uses an object relies on knowledge of the ACTUAL type of an object, or on a specific variant of `foo()` being called, then its design sort-of defeats the purpose of having a polymorphic base class and other classes that derive from it.

In the above, the compiler will still support virtual function calls (vtable, etc, if that is now the compiler works) and that may affect the process of creating and destroying objects.

Another technique to avoid dynamic dispatch (or binding) is to use templates (sometimes called compile-time polymorphism).     Essentially, the template may assume a type provides some interface (or set of operations) and will work with any variable of a type with that interface.   For example;

```
 struct X
 {
      void foo();
 };

 template<class T> void func()
 {
      T x;          // relies on T being instantiable (and destructible)
      x.foo();      // relies on T having a member named foo()
 }

 // in some function somewhere where both X and func() are known to the compiler

 func<X>();
```

Such templates do not need the type `T` to have virtual functions, so do not rely on dynamic dispatch (binding).   However, there is nothing stopping such a template function working with a class that has virtual member functions, so this does not disable dynamic binding - it only allows the programmer to make choices to avoid using dynamic binding.

If I was asked this question in interview, I'd probably point out all of the above, but leave it unsaid that the question is rather silly.  An interviewer knowledgeable about C++ will realise that, and just be interested in how you think through and address such a question   (after all real-world developers are often asked by management or customers to meet silly or unrealistic requirements, and are expected to be tactful enough to avoid telling their managers or customers they are being foolish).   If the interviewer has asked the question without understanding that (or without another member of the interview panel who understands that in the room) I wouldn't want to work with that employer anyway.

Comment: Well Said. Thanks Peter.

Answer (score -1):

you could avoid the overhead by  disabling RTTI...there is a compile time switch for that.

There wont be any overhead of virtual table dispatch, for dynamic_cast/typeid once RTTI disable flag is enabled.

Comment: But you have to take care of dynamic_cast/type id usage before you disable rtti..I think this is what the interviewer meant..

Comment: No RTTI doesn't mean no vtables.

Comment: agreed.But "disable dynamic binding feature" in the question makes me think, maybe this is what the interviewer meant.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. If it's any compile time flag to turned off RTTI , please let me know. It could be the possible answer for my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579887/how-expensive-is-rtti  this should help you .